# How can I find all subgraphs that match an unordered pattern and contain a root node?

Tags: algorithm, permutation, graph-theory

This started as a problem when trying to aggregate atoms within a chemical into possible fragments, but has since become a problem I'm just frustrated that I can't seem to solve or begin to tackle.

Here's the most formal way for me to pose the problem...

Given

- a graph where each node is labeled with a *non-unique* letter (A, B, C, D...)
- a root node index i
- a set S of letters e.g., (A, A, C)

Return a set of all connected (not necessarily fully connected) sub-graphs that contain the node at i *and* contain nodes that exactly match the set S in **any order**.

Really what I'd be looking for is just the sets of indices of each sub-graph.

A couple examples are shown below
[image: examples]

Comment: In your leftmost example, you have the set `{11A, 6A, 8B}`. This does not contain your root node `2B`. Is this a false positive or do you not actually care about the root node?

Comment: " each node is labeled with a non-unique letter"  it looks like each node is labelled with a combination of an index and a letter.

Comment: @ravenspoint yes, I edited the text for clarity. The nodes are marked by their (unique) index and some (non-unique) letter as a proxy for some other feature like atom symbol, a token describing a property, etc. I initially marked this detail separately but thought that it was harder to understand.

Comment: Note that salt ( NaCl ) is a chemical but not a molecule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that there are only two ways an atom can be included in one of your fragments:

1. The atom is connected directly to the root
2. The atom is connected to the root via other atoms that are also in the set S

So, the algorithm is

- IF letter on root is present in S

  - remove root letter from S
- SET L to list of nodes directly connected to root
- Add nodes connected to root through nodes with letter in S to L
- REMOVE nodes from L with letters absent from S
- Enumerate all subsets in L that match S to give subset list O
- IF letter on root is present in S

  - Add root to every subset in O
- LOOP G over subgraphs in O

  - LOOP N over nodes in G

    - IF N not connected directly to root

      - IF N is not reachable from root using only other nodes in G

        - Remove G from O
- OUTPUT O

**Here is a C++ implementation of this algorithm**

Declare the class

```
class cSolver
{
    raven::graph::sGraphData gd; // graph representation of molecule
    std::string root;
    std::vector<std::string> match; // required atoms
    std::vector<std::string> candidates;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> subGraphs;
    bool fRootInMatch;

    void sanity();
    void removeCandidatesNotInMatch();

    /// @brief Is there path from vertex to root through vertex types in match set
    /// @param vi
    /// @return
    bool isPathToRoot(int vi);

    void addCandidatesReachableFromRoot();

    void sortCandidates();

    std::vector<std::string>
    listRootConnected();

    void removeUnconnected();

    void addIfNovel(
        const std::vector<std::string> &vSelected);

    /// @brief select subgraph using first available atoms in permuted candidate list
    /// @return
    std::vector<std::string>
    select();

public:
    void solve();

    std::vector<std::string>
    text();

    void generate1();
    void setMatch(
        const std::string &s);
    bool setRoot(
        const std::string &s);
};
```

Generate the problem instance ( simplified version of your first example )

```
void cSolver::generate1()
{
    gd.g.clear();
    gd.g.add("2B", "1A");
    gd.g.add("2B", "3A");
    gd.g.add("2B", "4A");
    gd.g.add("2B", "5C");
    gd.g.add("3A", "10D");

    std::vector<std::string> m{
        "B", "A", "A"};
    match = m;

    root = "2B";
}
```

Implement the solve method

```
void cSolver::solve()
{
    sanity();

    // atoms connected directly to root
    candidates = listRootConnected();
    removeCandidatesNotInMatch();

    addCandidatesReachableFromRoot();

    sortCandidates();

    // loop over permuted lists of candidates
    do
    {
        select();

    } while (std::next_permutation(
        candidates.begin(), candidates.end()));

    // remove subgraphs that are not connected
    removeUnconnected();
}
```

Result display

[image]

Complete application code at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so76972353

Comment: This implies the solution would be recursive in nature. 
With each possible combination being found by starting with the neighbors of the root, "filling up" a possible set, then calling the same function with N-1 pieces missing from the set. This is slightly naive and would consume a lot of memory, but might do the trick for finding all possible instances. We can also immediately skip nodes that aren't in the set / possible remaining (needed) letters

Comment: Definitely a solution to finding unordered patterns in graphs. My first idea was to try existing libraries that use SMARTS queries, but I feel there are optimizations that can be made due to the unordered nature of the search as well as the fact that we've already tokenized the atoms in the molecule, thus not needing to do this extra work that VF2 normally would in, say, RDKit. Where we must check for aromaticity and other features to ensure the SMARTS query worked

Comment: No need for recursion.  See algorithm in updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! As it currently stands, I see the need to create the list of nodes that could be eligible for creating a matching set (L) but I don't see how this would guarantee that the subsets in the output would be guaranteed to be connected subsets. Is this the case?

Comment: FYI added code to implement algorithm